# Does the distance induced from a Riemannian metric on a manifold determine the Riemannian structure?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $(M, g), (N,h)$ be Riemannian manifolds and consider $d_g$ and $d_h$ the corresponding distance functions induced from $g$ and $h$.

Suppose $f: M \rightarrow N$ is a bijective isometry in the metric sense i.e. $d_h(f(x), f(y)) = d_g(x,y)$. Is it true that $f$ must be smooth and, moreover, that $f^* h = g$?

In more generality, if $M$ and $N$ are only smooth manifolds and $d_M, d_N$ are smooth distance functions, is it true that a bijective isometry $f: M \rightarrow N$ must be smooth?

Comment: Just think a bit more about your question: All your metric knows is topology (unless it is a Riemannian distance)...

Comment: A metric determines the opens, smoothness of maps on the manifold is still defined via charts.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I didn't know that any topological manifold is metrizable, but now I do, there's an answer here which explains it well. The question remains for distances coming from a Riemannian metric. I think I heard once that any isometry in the sense of preserving the distance function is in fact smooth and pulls back well the corresponding Riemannian metric tensors. Is it true?

Comment: Yes, the answer is totally different and it was discussed a number of times at MSE, so it might be a duplicate. My suggestion is to edit your question to reflect what you are actually interested in. Then I can add an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is the content of the [Myers-Steenrod theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myers%E2%80%93Steenrod_theorem).

Besides the Wikipedia references, you can find a proof for instance in

*Petersen, Peter*, [**Riemannian geometry**](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-29403-2), Graduate Texts in Mathematics 171. New York, NY: Springer (ISBN 0-387-29246-2/hbk). xvi, 401 p. (2006). [ZBL1220.53002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1220.53002).