# Given a manifold $(M,g)$, and a $f_\alpha(x):=\exp _p(\alpha x)$, why $h_\alpha:=\alpha^{-2} f_\alpha^* g \rightarrow$ the Euclidean metric.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Given a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$,  and an exponential map $f_\alpha: B_1 \rightarrow M$ which is given by $$f_\alpha(x):=\exp _{x_0}(\alpha x),$$
where $\exp _p$ is the exponential map at $p$, then define $$h_\alpha:=\alpha^{-2} f_\alpha^* g,$$
which is a  metric on $B_1$.

We have $$
\begin{aligned}
h_{\alpha, i j} & :=h_\alpha\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}, \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right)=\alpha^{-2} g\left(\frac{\partial f_\alpha}{\partial x^i}, \frac{\partial f_\alpha}{\partial x^j}\right)=: \alpha^{-2} g_{i j} \\
\sqrt{h_\alpha} & :=\sqrt{\operatorname{det}\left(h_{\alpha, i j}\right)}=\alpha^{-2 m} \sqrt{\operatorname{det}\left(g_{i j}\right)}=: \alpha^{-2 m} \sqrt{g},
\end{aligned}
$$
I wonder why $h_\alpha \rightarrow|d x|^2$ as $\alpha \rightarrow 0$ in $C^{\ell}\left(B_1\right)$ for every $\ell$, where $|d x|^2$ denotes the Euclidean metric.

**My attempt:**
Consider $$
f_\alpha:=\exp _{x_0}(\alpha x): (B_1, h_\alpha) \rightarrow (M,g_\alpha),
$$
and $$
\alpha^{-2}f_\alpha^* g_\alpha=h_\alpha.
$$
Following [REF1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/215573/square-of-the-distance-function-on-a-riemannian-manifold?_gl=1*19uoi2c*_ga*MjM1OTg3OC4xNjU1MzY0NTU1*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTY5ODgyNTk3Mi40ODYuMS4xNjk4ODM3NjA1LjAuMC4w), we have
$$
d_{g_\alpha}^2\left(\exp _{x 0}(\alpha v), \exp _{x_0}(\alpha w)\right)=|v-w|^2 \alpha^2-\frac{1}{3} R(v, w, w, v) \alpha^4+O\left(\alpha^5\right)=d_{h_\alpha}^2(v,w),
$$
then when $\alpha\rightarrow0$ $$\frac{d_{g_\alpha}^2(\exp _{x 0}(\alpha v), \exp _{x_0}(\alpha w)) }{ \alpha^2} \rightarrow|v-w|^2$$
which is distance function in Euclidean space. Then I read [REF2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4696630/does-the-distance-induced-from-a-riemannian-metric-on-a-manifold-determine-the-r), when $\alpha\rightarrow0$
$$
\alpha^{-2}f_\alpha^* g_\alpha=h_\alpha,
$$
which is the Euclidean metric.

Comment: What does $g_{ij}$ mean here? It obviously needs to depend on $\alpha$. You should probably start by computing this explicitly for an example, like $M=S^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried to compute for $S^2$, but after writing the expression of exponential map from $T_p(S^2)$ to $S^2$, I don't know how to calculate the push-forward of this map. I wonder if this two answers can give a proof to my question. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/215573/square-of-the-distance-function-on-a-riemannian-manifold?_gl=1*19uoi2c*_ga*MjM1OTg3OC4xNjU1MzY0NTU1*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTY5ODgyNTk3Mi40ODYuMS4xNjk4ODM3NjA1LjAuMC4w and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4696630/does-the-distance-induced-from-a-riemannian-metric-on-a-manifold-determine-the-r

Comment: I add a 'My attempt' in my question.

Comment: Here's the computation for $S^2$: Let $x_0$ be the north pole of $S^2$. Write $v\in T_{x_0}S^2$ as $v=t(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$, the $(\phi,\theta)$ coordinates (using "American mathematical" spherical coordinates) of $\exp_{x_0}(\alpha v)$ are $\phi=\alpha t$, $\theta=\theta$. The metric on $S^2$ is $ds^2=d\phi\otimes d\phi + \sin^2\phi\,d\theta\otimes d\theta$, so $h_\alpha=\alpha^{-2}\left(\alpha^2 dt\otimes dt + \sin^2 (\alpha t)\,d\theta\otimes d\theta\right) \to dt\otimes dt + t^2 d\theta\otimes d\theta$, as desired.